# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object refer

Tags: java, android, xml, android-arrayadapter, virtual

I am trying to make a single screen simple app for displaying listview but this error occurred, ReportCard is the ArrayAdapter class.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.vitikasoni.reportcard;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<Student> s = new ArrayList<Student>();
        s.add(new Student("Vitika", 87, 79, 93, 89));
        s.add(new Student("Faizal", 90, 95, 89, 99));
        s.add(new Student("Prince", 83, 73, 92, 67));
        s.add(new Student("Sejal", 83, 79, 95, 79));

        ReportCard r = new ReportCard(this, s);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(r);
    }
}
```

view_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/na"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/m"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/e"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="English:98" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ev"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="EVS:98" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/h"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Hindi:98" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/p"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Percent:98%" />
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Reportcard.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReportCard extends ArrayAdapter<Student> {
    public ReportCard(Context c, ArrayList<Student> s) {
        super(c, 0, s);
    }

    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
        }
        Student currentWord = getItem(position);

        TextView na = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.na);
        na.setText(currentWord.getName());

        TextView m = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.m);
        m.setText(currentWord.getMaths());

        TextView h = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.h);
        h.setText(currentWord.getHindi());

        TextView e = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.e);
        e.setText(currentWord.getEng());

        TextView ev = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.ev);
        ev.setText(currentWord.getEvs());

        TextView p = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.p);

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

Student.java

```
package com.vitikasoni.reportcard;

public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int eng;
    private int maths;
    private int hindi;
    private int evs;
    private double per;

    public Student(String n, int e, int m, int h, int ev) {
        name = n;
        eng = e;
        maths = m;
        hindi = h;
        evs = ev;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getEng() {
        return eng;
    }

    public int getHindi() {
        return hindi;
    }

    public int getEvs() {
        return evs;
    }

    public int getMaths() {
        return maths;
    }

    public double getPer() {
        double pr = (eng + hindi + maths + evs) / 4;
        return pr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First set correct `layout id` for `ListView` adapter to overcome `Null Pointer Exception`  which you currently have. After fix this your code won't run because  there is another problem and you definitely get `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4f` exception.

Problem at your `setText(currentWord.getMaths())` line because here `currentWord.getMaths()` is `integer` type and `setText(integer)` considers this `interger` paramer as `R.string.someName`.

So either change `private int maths;` to `private String  maths;` You have to change all `interger` type to `String` type.

**OR**

use below code in `getView()` method of Adapter.

// Here I am concating `integer` to `String` and setting to `TextView`

```
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.view_view, parent, false);
        }
        Student currentWord = getItem(position);

        TextView na = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.na);
        na.setText(currentWord.getName());

        TextView m = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.m);
        m.setText(currentWord.getMaths()+"");

        TextView h = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.h);
        h.setText(currentWord.getHindi()+"");

        TextView e = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.e);
        e.setText(currentWord.getEng()+"");

        TextView ev = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.ev);
        ev.setText(currentWord.getEvs()+"");

        TextView p = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.p);

        return listItemView;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!   :)

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the wrong layout as your adapter item view.

change this

```
listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
```

with

```
listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_view, parent, false);
```

Comment: After changing this there will be a crash !!!      android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4f

Comment: @NRUSINGHAMOHARANA There might be other problems in the code as OP hasn't provided any stack trace. However, the layout needs to be changed as you can see all the reference OP using in adapter class is from the layout view_view.xml file.

Comment: Yeah I understood. What I am trying to say is , your solution is absolutely solve NPE but app won't run after that. Just chill bro. I have run code successfully and updated my answer.